# How to add a new property to a Json object while iterating

Tags: java, json

I want to basically merge data from several json files into one final json file.
The following stripped down version of the code searches for a property, let's say 'label' and updates its value 'new_value'.

This works so far.

But what I need now, is **a new property within the node**, where the search succeeds.
So basically a new property under 'label' named 'label_new' with value to 'new_value'.

Here is a basic recursive implementation. I know that I need to replace somehow, but every attempt I tried did not work.

Any suggestion that may help?
-Thx

Java:

```
  private static Object k = null;
  private static Object v = null;
  private static Object parent = null;

  public static void iterate(Object obj, JSONObject props, String search) throws Exception {
    try {
      if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
        parent = obj;
        for (Iterator it = ((JSONObject) obj).keys(); it.hasNext();) {
          k = it.next();
          v = ((JSONObject) obj).get((String) k);
          iterate(v, props, search);
        }
      }
      if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((JSONArray) obj).length(); i++) {
          v = ((JSONArray) obj).get(i);
          iterate(v, props, search);
        }
      }
      if (obj instanceof String) {
        if (k.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(search)) {
          ((JSONObject) parent).put(search, "NEW_VALUE");
          // ((JSONObject) parent).put(search + "_new", "NEW_VALUE");
        }
      }
    } finally {
    }
```

The starting json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "group": {
            "subGroup": {
                "boolean": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "test",
                    "label": "new_value"
                },
                "description": "test",
                "label": "test",
                "text": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "test",
                    "label": "new_value"
                }
            },
            "name": "test",
            "description": "test",
            "label": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

The final output I need:

```
{
    "data": {
        "group": {
            "subGroup": {
                "boolean": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "test",
                    "label": "new_value",
                    "label_new": "new_value"
                },
                "description": "test",
                "label": "test",
                "text": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "label": "new_value",
                    "label_new": "new_value"
                }
            },
            "name": "test",
            "description": "test",
            "label": "new_value",
            "label_new": "new_value"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

```java
private static Object k = null;
private static Object v = null;

public static void iterate(Object obj, Object parent, JSONObject props, String search) throws Exception {
  try {
    if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
      for (Iterator it = ((JSONObject) obj).keys(); it.hasNext();) {
        k = it.next();
        v = ((JSONObject) obj).get((String) k);
        iterate(v, obj, props, search);
      }
    }
    if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
      for (int i = 0; i < ((JSONArray) obj).length(); i++) {
        v = ((JSONArray) obj).get(i);
        iterate(v, obj, props, search);
      }
    }
    if (obj instanceof String) {
      if (k.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(search)) {
        // ((JSONObject) parent).put(search, "TEST_A_NEW_VALUE");
        ((JSONObject) parent).put(search + "_new", "TEST_A_NEW_VALUE");
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) { // throws ConcurrentModificationException
    ex.getMessage();
  } finally {
  }
} // iterate
```

The Starting json:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "group": {
            "subGroup": {
                "boolean": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "test",
                    "label": "test"
                },
                "description": "test",
                "label": "test",
                "text": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "test",
                    "label": "test"
                },
                "choice": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "test",
                    "label": "test",
                    "items": {
                        "item": [
                            {
                                "label": "test"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "test"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "test"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": "test",
            "description": "test",
            "label": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

The current output. While iterating, I get an `ConcurrentModificationException`.
`label` within `item` is not updated. But that is want I want.

```json
{
    "data": {
        "group": {
            "subGroup": {
                "description": "test",
                "label": "test",
                "choice": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "test",
                    "label": "test",
                    "items": {
                        "item": [
                            {
                                "label": "test",
                                "label_new": "TEST_A_NEW_VALUE"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "test",
                                "label_new": "TEST_A_NEW_VALUE"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "test",
                                "label_new": "TEST_A_NEW_VALUE"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "label_new": "TEST_A_NEW_VALUE"
            },
            "name": "test",
            "description": "test",
            "label": "test",
            "label_new": "TEST_A_NEW_VALUE"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `parent` is a global variable? Pass it as a parameter to `iterate`, pass root object at the first call.

Comment: I think it doesn't really matter. I tried passing it as you mention it already. But the problem I'm seeing is, that my `parent` is at the moment, when the search matches, `boolean`. But I should somehow have `subGroup` at my fingertips, to replace the `boolean` node with a new property.

Comment: Can you provide an output when it's not working?

Comment: I have to correct myself. Your suggestion works, thx! But if I run the actual data json against it (and not this simplified version), I get an `ConcurrentModificationException` exception. I try to boil the data json down, till I can reproduce the error.

Comment: Probably, you should check if the searched key is present, if it's an object, add it, and only then traverse objects inside it.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce the Exception in a small example. I will update my question shortly.

Answer (score 0):

First, pass `parent` as a parameter, it makes more sense, and having it as a global variable may be prone to errors.
Second, to avoid concurrent modification, insert the new key after traversing the object:

```
if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Iterator it = ((JSONObject) obj).keys(); it.hasNext();) {
        k = it.next();
        v = ((JSONObject) obj).get((String) k);
        if (v instanceof JSONArray || v instanceof JSONObject) {
            iterate(v, obj, props, search); // second parameter is the parent
        } else if (v instanceof String) {
            if (!found && search.equalsIgnoreCase(v)) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
     }

     if (found) {
         // insert 'new' entry
     }
 }
```

Comment: I tested your approach, but still not all `label` nodes are updated. (See my update)

Comment: @oldsport Have you tried to debug it? What happens, when iterating the `JSONArray`?